# Two EC2 instances can't see each other in the private network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

**My initial goal:** Create a OpenVPN access server on AWS so I can only connect to another EC2 instance using the VPN. The second EC2 instance is not allowed to have any kind of public access.

This didn't work for me because the VPN wouldn't let me connect to the EC2 instance. I always got a timeout. After some troubleshooting I found out that they are not in the same private network so they can't see each other. They are in the same VPC and in the same Subnet. The security groups are both wide open. I realized it could be an issue with OpenVPN and my config.

The second EC2 instance is a normal Windows Server 2019 instance.

So I opened a 3rd EC2 instance that is also running Windows Server 2019. I used the remote desktop to control the second EC2 instance. After opening cmd and using `ipconfig` and `apr -a` I couldn't find the 3rd EC2 instance again in the local network. Showing me again that they are not in the same local network. How can I set the EC2 instances up so they are both on the same local network?

Comment: why do you need an openvpn to communicate between two instances from the same network

Comment: What do you mean by "same local network"? If they are in the same VPC, and especially the same subnet, then they are in the same network. Do you have the AWS Security Group rules, and Windows firewall rules configured correctly to allow network communication between the EC2 servers?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your situation is:

- You want to have resources in a VPC that are private (not accessible from the Internet)
- You want to be able to access these resources via OpenVPN from the Internet

The architecture should be:

- A VPC with at least one public subnet and at least one private subnet
- Put the OpenVPN server in a **public subnet** with a Security Group that permits inbound VPN access from your computer on the Internet (it appears that this is working for you)
- Put all other resources in a **private subnet**
- The Security Group(s) associated with the other resources should **permit inbound access either from the OpenVPN server** (they can refer to the OpenVPN security group by ID) or to the CIDR range of the VPC (thus allowing resources to communicate with each other within the VPC)
- If you wish for the other instances to have outbound Internet access (eg for downloading software), then you will also need a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet, with the Route Table for the private subnets pointing to the NAT Gateway for destination `0.0.0.0/0`

You might also need to adjust the **Firewall settings on the Windows instances** to permit all necessary traffic.